# Start CSS animation after scrolling to particular section of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate images using CSS on a webpage. The animation is working fine but I want to START the animation it only when user reaches at a particular section of the page. Here is my code:

```
<div class="sec1-right">
   <img class="sec1-dmush1" src ="sec1-dmush1.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sec1-right{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 600px;
    margin-top: 86px;
}

/* first section animation */
.sec1-dmush1 {
    animation: fadeAndScale .9s cubic-bezier(.45,-0.22,.34,1.69);
    transform-origin:center bottom;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    top: 300px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Animation

```
@keyframes fadeAndScale{
    from{
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale3d(0,0,1);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve

Comment: maybe this will help you https://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: How do you want to achieve it? By using jquery, pure javascript or some scrolling plugins like [waypoint js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) will work for you?

Comment: My preference is javascript and then jquery @locateganesh

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `scroll` event in javascript. element `offsetTop` minus `window` height. So as soon as element comes in viewport event starts.

**Javascript:**

```
var scrollpos = window.scrollY; // window scroll position
var wh = window.innerHeight-50; // as soon as element touches bottom with offset event starts
var element = document.querySelector(".sec1-dmush1"); //element

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ 
    if(scrollpos > (element.offsetTop - wh)){
        element.classList.add("onScroll");
    }
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gtojg6b4/16/)

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var wh = $(window).height()-50;
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $('.sec1-dmush1').offset().top-wh){
    $('.sec1-dmush1').addClass('onScroll');
  }
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gtojg6b4/9/)

If you have multiple elements to animate. You can use **[waypoint js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)** to reduce some efforts.

```
var wh = $(window).height();
var waypoints = $('.sec1-dmush1').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(this.element).addClass('onScroll');
  console.log(11);
}, {
    offset: wh-50
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gtojg6b4/17/)

Answer (score -2):

using javascript you can find the scroll event . After the specific px(height). You can add a class to the existing class(jquery) for which you trying to animate.

Comment: you don't need jquery to add a class to an element, but the basic answer would work.